# How to add this category in marketing menu?

Tags: magento2, category-tree, tabs

[image]

I want to add new category called aaa and a link called bbb.. in magento2

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your extension you have to create a new file `menu.xml`
`Foo/Bar/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Foo_Bar::foo_bar" title="Foo Bar" module="Foo_Bar" sortOrder="10" parent="Magento_Backend::marketing_user_content" action="foo/bar" resource="Foo_Bar::foo_bar"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

The important part is the `parent="Magento_Backend::marketing_user_content"` for the sub-menu and the `action="foo/bar"` for the link

If you want an example you can take the `Reviews` one in `magento/module-review/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml` with the line

```
<add id="Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_reviews_all" title="Reviews" translate="title" module="Magento_Review" parent="Magento_Backend::marketing_user_content" sortOrder="10" action="review/product/index" resource="Magento_Review::reviews_all"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I am clicking on the MARKETING icon and then on my new category
[image]

The MARKETING icon doens't has a hover on the icon..

what should I do to make the MARKETING ICON be a hover on it,
when I am in my new page... ?

Any help ?
Thanks.

Comment: ? any help ? Thanks...